# Token name wrong in Phantom wallet

Tags: wallet, metadata

we changed the metadata on our token but it still shows the same name on Phantom wallet. Is there a way to get it changed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this
1 Refresh the Wallet: Close and reopen your Phantom wallet to see if the changes take effect.

2 Clear Cache: Clear the cache of your Phantom wallet. This option is usually available in the wallet settings.

3 Token Re-Add: Remove the token from your wallet and then re-add it with the updated metadata.

If the issue persists after trying these steps, you may need to contact the support team of the token or Phantom wallet for further assistance. They should be able to guide you on how to update the token name correctly.

I hope this helps.